# How to change error-message displayed @ failed form-element validation to be different than the element's '#title" text?

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

I'm writing a custom form module.

Using Drupal7's FormAPI, I create a checkbox, the label/text diplayed next to it is set as described here

```
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#checkbox
```

with the #title property,

```
    $form['test'] = array(
    '#type'     => 'checkbox',
    '#title'    => t('This is the text that gets displayed next to the checkbox'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );
```

which then displays in the browser,

```
[ ] This is the text that gets displayed next to the checkbox
```

Ih there's an error in submission that involves that checkbox, e.g. in the example above being required but not being checked, an error box is shown across the top content-area that says

```
"X  The This is the text that gets displayed next to the checkbox field is required"
```

I want to change that displayed error message to something other than the label/text.  For example, on error,

```
"X  Selecting the displayed checkbox is required."
```

or

```
"X  You forgot to check the required checkbox.  Please try again."
```

How do I set the error-message text to be different that the assigned label/text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a basic form in a custom module:

```
    function customform_demo($form, $form_state) {
    $form['test'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title'    => t('This is the text that gets displayed next to the checkbox'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['test_submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );

    return $form;

}
```

You can set a custom error message in the form validation function. Here is a basic example with some comments:

```
    function customform_demo_validate($form, &$form_state) {

    // Test for existing form errors
    if (form_get_errors()) {

        // Save errors
        $form_errors = form_get_errors();
        $drupal_errors = drupal_get_messages('error');

        // Clear form errors
        form_clear_error();

        foreach($drupal_errors['error'] as $key => $error) {
            if (in_array($error, $form_errors)) {
                // Unset form errors
                unset($drupal_errors['error'][$key]);
            }
        }

        // Rebuild drupal errors
        foreach($drupal_errors['error'] as $key => $message) {
            drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
        }

        // Validate form field and set error message    
        if ( $form_state['values']['test'] === 0 ) {
            form_set_error('test', t('You forgot to check the required checkbox. Please try again.'));
        }

                // Add more validation tests and error messages

    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! I was looking in the completely wrong place for this solution!  THanks