# Remove drupal message "field is required" from webform validation

Tags: 7, webforms

So when a webform is validated it sends a drupal message "X field is required", and creates a red border around the field.

For our project the red border is enough, how would I go about removing Drupal messages from triggering during validation?

Comment: Try this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39851/how-to-change-error-message-displayed-failed-form-element-validation-to-be-dif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it using CSS in that particular page !

Check for specific div's the page body is using and set the div.error to display:none;

OR

Override [theme_status_messages](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7) to exclude or alter the status messages.

In your case,

```
function your_theme_status_messages($variables) {
  $display = $variables['display'];
  $output = '';

  $status_heading = array(
    'status' => t('Status message'), 
    'error' => t('Error message'), 
    'warning' => t('Warning message'),
  );
  foreach (drupal_get_messages($display) as $type => $messages) {
    $output .= "<div class=\"messages $type\">\n";
    if (!empty($status_heading[$type])) {
      $output .= '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . $status_heading[$type] . "</h2>\n";
    }
    if (count($messages) > 1) {
      $output .= " <ul>\n";
      foreach ($messages as $message) {
        if (strpos($a,'required') === false) {  // Check for any other conditions here
          $output .= '  <li>' . $message . "</li>\n";
        }
      }
      $output .= " </ul>\n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= $messages[0];
    }
    $output .= "</div>\n";
  }
  return $output;
}
```