# Custom form set error for user login validate

Tags: hooks

I have used a custom validate function.

```
function user_information_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login' || 'user_login_block') {
    array_unshift($form['#validate'],'user_information_user_login_form_validate');
  }
}

function user_information_user_login_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // print_r($form_state);
  form_set_error('name', t('Password invalid'));
}
```

But I am unable to log in to the site any more.

Answer (score 1):

you cant submit your form because you have set the error.

**the form set error should be applied inside some condition**

```
 function user_information_user_login_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
    //print_r($form_state);
    //set some condition 
     if($form_state["some_field"] != "somevalue")// only when the condition satisfies the form set error should display. if not all the time your from set error will be called 
      form_set_error('name', t('Password invalid'));
    }
```

above condition is a sample condition you have to replace it with your own condition for validating your password.

Comment: Ok I have to check if the username and password is not correct then display this sententce. In essence I will have to overwrite this message "Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password? "

Comment: refer this for overwrite the form set error message http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39851/how-to-change-error-message-displayed-failed-form-element-validation-to-be-dif%5D